# Treat arrow keyboard keys normally when TextInput is in focus but fire an intent otherwise

Tags: flutter

I am using `Shortcuts` to trigger intents on arrow keys. This works well and I would like to keep using the arrow keys as they are seemingly the most intuitive. Yet, this comes with a problem, when inside of a `TextInput`, using the keyboard arrow keys no longer works normally.

How can I have the Flutter shortcut system act "normally" when inside of `TextInput`--so that if a user clicks the left arrow key, it merely moves the cursor backwards, and if a user clicks the right arrow, it moves the cursor forward? And yet, trigger an intent/action when outside of a `TextInput`?

Something like:

```
Focus(
      onKey: (node, event) {
        final currentlyFocusedNode = FocusManager.instance.primaryFocus;

        if (currentlyFocusedNode is FocusNode &&
            currentlyFocusedNode.context is EditableText) {
          // act normally in a TextInput
        }

      },
      child: TextFormField(),
    );
  }
```

Using @jmatth's solution (big thanks), I extended it to this:

```dart
  return DefaultTextEditingShortcuts(
    child: Focus(
      onKey: (node, event) {
        const escapeKey = LogicalKeyboardKey.escape;
        const enterKey = LogicalKeyboardKey.enter;

        if (event.isKeyPressed(escapeKey)) {
          widget.onMutationAbandoned();
        }

        if (event.isKeyPressed(enterKey)) {
          widget.onMutationCompleted();
        }

        return KeyEventResult.ignored;
      },
      child: TextFormField(
        autofocus: true,
        focusNode: focusNode..requestFocus(),
        onChanged: (value) => widget.onTextChanged(value),
        initialValue: widget.text.isNotEmpty ? widget.text : null,
        // onFieldSubmitted: (_) => onMutationCompleted(),
      ),
    ),
  );
```

This has resulted in the `TextFormField` working expectedly, but when text input is submitted or escaped, the other keyboard shortcuts no longer work, as it seems that the base `Shortcuts` widget is no longer in focus itself, and can only be accessed again via tab traversal, which is not ideal, the shortcuts in the `Shortcuts` widget should work after a user submits new text or escapes from the operation in the `TextFormField`.

Am I forgetting to forfeit focus or pass it back to the shortcuts widget up the tree? I assumed it would just go back to the previous focus state when the `TextFormField` is removed from the tree (`onMutationCompleted` or `onMutationAbandoned` takes it out when text editing is terminated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the text fields in [`DefaultTextEditingShortcuts`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/DefaultTextEditingShortcuts-class.html).

```dart
DefaultTextEditingShortcuts(
  child: TextFormField(),
),
```